# Change image asset path in Webpack config

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I am having issues with Webpack/Encore where my image URLs are not pulling through correctly.

`homepage.scss`:

```
body {
    background: #FFEFE2 url("../../img/bg.jpg") no-repeat;
}
```

The generated markup is:

```
body {
    background: #FFEFE2 url(/build/images/bg.9f6bc44a.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

My application sits under `/app`, so the correct URL would be `/app/build/images/bg.9f6bc44a.jpg`.

My Webpack encore config:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('web/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './web/assets/js/app.js')

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Comment: You should modify the `file-loader`'s `publicPath` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Encore
   // directory where compiled assets will be stored
   .setOutputPath('web/build/')
   // public path used by the web server to access the output path
   .setPublicPath('/app/build')
   // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
   .setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')
```

Just change currentPath and `setManifestKeyPrefix` .

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also had to call `setManifestKeyPrefix` and have updated your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Copy [Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin). After adding it to your dependencies, change your 
webpack.config.js like this:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

.addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
.....
.addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        // copies to {output}/static
        { from: './assets/static', to: 'static' }
    ]))
;
```

After restart Encore, you can use images just like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('build/static/foo.jpg') }}" />
```